# Как задать какой именно браузер chrome будут запущен командой chrome в командной строке

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

В системе установлено несколько разных chromium браузеров, в VSCode есть расширение Live server, оно запускает браузер командой chrome с параметрами, и всегда запускается последний установленный chromium, а хотелось бы что бы запускался всегда конкретный, проблема встречается как на linux так и на win. В переменных среды не нашёл ничего о chrome.

Comment: в windows частично решает проблему удаление других похожих на HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ChromeHTML веток в реестре, и прописывание путей в этом, ведущих к exe нужного хрома.